# How to install Sugar ORM on my android project

Tags: android, orm, android-gradle-plugin

Someone suggested me to use Sugar ORM and provided a link to the website.

http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

In the website it tells me how to download the thing:

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
```

I guess I need to put that in one of my gradle files. But which one? And where to put it in the file? I guess the most possible two are:

```
build.gradle (Project:MyProjetName)
build.gradle (Module:app)
```

Can you tell me where to put the statement?

Comment: use GreenDAO or DBFlow, more [here](https://github.com/Raizlabs/AndroidDatabaseLibraryComparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to the build.gradle for Module:app. It will go in the dependencies block.